# Trouble installing dropboxpython api (with ssl) on webfaction

Tags: python, django, dropbox-api, webfaction

I developed a Django app that uses the dropbox api. On my development environment on windows it works perfect which uses python 2.7. I tried deploying it to my site (hosted by webfaction), which I originally setup with python 2.5. If I try to run

> python2.5 setup.py install

from the dropbox-1.3 api directory I get this error:

> The package setup script has attempted to modify files on your system
>   that are not within the EasyInstall build area, and has been aborted.
>
> This package cannot be safely installed by EasyInstall, and may not
>   support alternate installation locations even if you run its setup
>   script by hand.  Please inform the package's author and the
>   EasyInstall maintainers to find out if a fix or workaround is
>   available.

This seems to happen after it tries to process dependencies and tries to install "ssl". I'm not sure how to work around this?

Comment: I just upgraded to python 2.7 because nothing else seemed to be working. That fixed the issue. The dropbox api installed without issue.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently installing the SSL package works if you download the tarball, unpack it, and then run setup.py yourself in the directory.

After that's installed, you should be able to install the Dropbox package.

SSL: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/ssl